# Browsing ouside VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client, openconnect

My company asks to connect thru a VPN client (Cisco), but when I do I lose access to a bunch of sites.

In a solution I found here, installing OpenConnect solved the issue, as it uses the same protocol and I found that browsing is not blocked this way.

I thought that was a win, but checking my speed at speedtest.net I saw that my external IP was still the one VPN assigned and that my speed was very limited compared to my home ISP plan.

At first, I assumed that even though my browsing is not blocked, the trafic is still being routed thru the VPN. But an interesting fact is that if I download a large file while on OpenConnect VPN, the speed is fast, and when I did the same on Cisco VPN is would take an eternity.

What way can I be certain what network i am using while browsing and listening to music streams while connected to OpenConnect VPN? What can explain the difference in speeds?

Bellow is my route print result (edited to mask addresses):

````
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0       192.x.x.x       192.x.x.y     26
        0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0        10.x.x.x       10.x.x.y      2
        10.x.x.x     255.255.255.0         On-link       10.x.x.y    257
        10.x.x.x   255.255.255.255         On-link       10.x.x.x    257
        10.x.x.x   255.255.255.255         On-link       10.x.x.x    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link       127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       127.0.0.1    331
        127.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       127.0.0.1    331
        169.x.x.x      255.255.0.0         On-link       169.x.x.x    281
        169.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.x.x.x    281
        169.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.x.x.x    281
        172.x.x.x  255.255.255.240         On-link       172.x.x.x   5256
        172.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.x.x.x   5256
        172.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.x.x.x   5256
        177.x.x.x  255.255.255.255       192.x.x.x       192.x.x.x     26
        192.x.x.x    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.x.x.x    281
        192.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.x.x.x    281
        192.x.x.x  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.x.x.x    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.x.x.x    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       169.x.x.x    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.x.x.x    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.x.x.x   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.x.x.x    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.x.x.x    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.x.x.x    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.x.x.x   5256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.x.x.x       1
=========================================================================== ```
````

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN, open powershell and type  `Get-VPNConnection` . Does it return results? If so, you may be able to turn on split tunneling using `Set-VPNConnection -Name "name_in_first_command" -SplitTunneling $True`, otherwise look for a split tunneling setting in the client and turn it on.

Comment: No luck, the command return nothing and the OpenConnect client has no such option that I could locate

Comment: Is this a work or personal computer?

Comment: @music2myear - For the purposes of the question I am not sure it really matters.  What is clear is the author is attempting to bypass something has been intentionally implemented by the companies network Administrator.  The route table is clearly an enterprise network.  *This is clearly question with regards to WFH, so the use of the VPN is required, to get to the companies network infrastructure.*

Comment: Its a personal computer at my home that needs VPN to access a remote desktop at work.
I am considering creating a VM, but that would eat up resources I need for my local dev tools

Comment: I changed the Metric of the VPN gateway to 100 and now it seems like external sites see me as my original ISP IP, instead of an IP in the city where the VPN connects to.
Do this does the trick, what are the downsides without any further changes to the routes?

Comment: @Ramhound yes. If the VPN is required for work then work owns that connection and can do with it as they please. But, a personal computer doesn't belong to work and so there could be valid reasons to wish to route some traffic outside the VPN.

Comment: @Welsige the problem is that anything you try may result in negative action by your employer as they may see this as attempting to circumvent their policies governing your work for them. I'd go with the VM option. Keep their traffic on their own isolated system and so the main computer is free to be your own.